# Linear Algebra - $n\times n$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be any $n \times n$ defined over the real numbers.

Let assume that $I+AB$ invertible matrix.

Prove :

- $I+BA$ invertible matrix
- $(I+BA)^{-1}=I-B(I+AB)^{-1}A$

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$(I+BA)\left(I-B(I+AB)^{-1}A\right)=I-B(I+AB)^{-1}A+BA-BAB(I+AB)^{-1}A =$$

$$I-B\left((I+AB)^{-1}-I+AB(I+AB)^{-1}\right)A=I-B\left(\overbrace{(I+AB)^{-1}\left(I+AB)-I\right)}^{=I-I=0}\right)A=I$$

Comment: I don't understand how $I-B(I+AB)^{-1}A+BA-BAB(I+AB)^{-1}A = I-B\left((I+AB)^{-1}-I+AB(I+AB)^{-1}\right)A$ Could you please add an extra step or two?

Comment: @JaVaPG : Develop the second expression, you will get the first one.

Comment: @JaVaPG , left/right distributivity: put for simplicity $\;K:=(I+AB)^{-1}\;$: $$BKA+BA-BABKA=B(KA+A-ABKA)=B(K+I-ABK)A$$

Comment: @Timbuc Now its clear thank you, but I still don't understand why $I-B \left((I+AB)^{-1}-I+AB(I+AB)^{-1} \right)A=I- \left( \overbrace{(I+AB)^{-1} \left(I+AB)-I \right)}^{=I-I=0} \right)$  also you didn't prove that $I+BA$ invertible matrix, thank you for your help.

Comment: @JaVaPG, you need to be more careful and put a little more attention to details. Writing down the given expression most probably will help a lot. What we have in that big parentheses on the right is $$K^{-1}K-I=I-I=0\ldots \ldots !$$ and what the above proved is that $\;K:=I+BA\;$ multiplied by some matrix (the one you're given!) is the identity matrix, and this means the matrix is invertible, so **it is too** proved .

Comment: @Timbuc I'm sorry I think I was clear enough, The big parentheses are clear, the problem is $I-B \left((I+AB)^{-1}-I+AB(I+AB)^{-1} \right)A \rightarrow I- \left( \overbrace{(I+AB)^{-1} \left(I+AB)-I \right)}^{=I-I=0} \right)$ I tried to write it as K but I still don't understand.

Comment: Perhaps I misled you, @JaVaPG: in my answer, on the right side, I forgot to multiply by $\;B\;$ on the left and by $\;A\;$ on the right. The final result is the same, of course. I already edited my answer.

Comment: @Timbuc The equation that I don't understand $((I+AB)^{-1}-I+AB(I+AB)^{-1})=(I+AB)^{-1}(I+AB)-I)$

Comment: That is distributivity, @JaVaPG !! I'm sorry but I cannot help you any more if you don't see it: **AGAIN**, put $\;K=(I+AB)^{-1}\;$ , then that equation simply says $$(K-I+ABK)=K(I+AB)-I$$ and since $\;K=(I+AB)^{-1}\;$ , then $\;K(I+AB)=I\;$ ...If you don't understand the step $\;K+ABK=(I+AB)K=K(I+AB)\;$ then I cannot do anything more. Perhaps someone else can explain it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Here $I−B(I+AB)^{−1}A$ exists and multiplying this with $(I+BA)$ gives us the $I$. Hence $(I+AB)$ is invertible. 2) is also satisfied by the uniqueness of the inverse.